# notifyall() - On threads that use static synch method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code that I am trying to print the threads according to the id 0,1,2 : but for some reason the notifyall() is not working for me, it prints only the first thread and seems that the other just keeps waiting.

```
public class WorkThread extends Thread {

    private int[] vec;
    private int id;
    private int res;
    static Integer printNowId = 0;

    public WorkThread(int[] vec, int id) {
        this.vec = vec;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public  synchronized void checkTurn(int id){
        while (id != printNowId){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public  synchronized void done(){
        printNowId = printNowId + 1 ;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public static synchronized int p(int[] vec, int id){
        int res = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<vec.length;i++){
            vec[i] = vec[i] + 1; 
            res = res +vec[i];
        }

        return res;
    }

    public  void run () {
        res = p(vec,id);
        checkTurn(id);
        System.out.println("task " + id + " res= " + res);
        done();
    }
}
```

public class DriverABCD {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    int vec[] = {1,2,3,4};
    WorkThread[] workers = new WorkThread[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        workers[i] = new WorkThread(vec,i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        workers[i].start();
    }

    System.out.println("main");
```

}

only the first thread is printed. and the other are not.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: It is *not* clear how your code is actually started/executed. And beyond that: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 5 minutes it takes to properly format/indent all of your source code - instead of dumping such a (sorry) lazy mess on us. Would you dare showing up with such input when talking to real person peers?!

Comment: thanks for ur comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong locking objects. You lock on each WorkThread, but WorkThread 0 does not release WorkThread 1 or 2 and vice versa.

What you need is ONE locking object for all WorkThread to synchronize. You can do with the following changes to your code.

```
public class WorkThread extends Thread {
...
   static Object lock = new Object();
...
   public void checkTurn(int id) {
     synchronized (lock) {
        while (id != printNowId) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
  }

   public void done() {
     synchronized (lock) {
        printNowId = printNowId + 1;
        lock.notifyAll();
     }
   }
...
```

The output looks like:

```
task 0 res= 14
main
task 1 res= 18
task 2 res= 22
```